# Reversed Cumulative sum in python - Assigning 0 to the bottom

Tags: python, pandas

I have wrote a python code but now stucked at getting 0 value to the bottom of the column. Pls refer the code I wrote

```
df2['cumsum_reverse'] = df2.loc[::-1, 'OS for the month'].cumsum()[::-1]
```

Below is the output table

[Click here for the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wj8MS.png)

In the end, I have added the column that need to come.

Can you help me for this issue?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) Also, a complete [MRE] would need sample data, expected output, and actual output. The [tour] and [ask] are also good places to get started. It can be a daunting and unintuitive site at first, but good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, use [`pandas.Series.shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) :

```
df2['cumsum_reverse'] = df2.loc[::-1, 'OS for the month'].shift().cumsum()[::-1].fillna("-")
```

Output :

```
print(df2['cumsum_reverse'])

2022-01     1610049.2
2022-02     1118224.93
2022-03     967592.69
2022-04             -
Name: cumsum_reverse, dtype: object
```